# hyperref and pagenote: No web links containing umlauts shown in pagenotes

Tags: hyperref, pagenote

The following MWE shows the problem: An internet-link with a German umlaut (ä ü ö ß) gives an error message when used within `\pagenote{}`. In the main body the use of `\href{}{}` or `\url{}` does *not* result in an error when such internet-links are used.

The pagenote-links with URL (href and url) including German umlauts result in an error:

> File ended while scanning use of \noteentry and will not be displayed in the pdf file as links in the pagenotes when having run pdflatex.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote

\begin{document}

\href{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki}{A link without german Umlaute ü ö ä ß -- in the ordinary text body}

\href{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles#Fr%C3%BChe_Jahre_(1956%E2%80%931960)}{A link including german Umlaute ä ö ü ß -- in the ordinary text body}

    A pagenote with an URL (href command) without german Umlaute ä ö ü ß:\pagenote{\href{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki}{A link without german Umlaute ü ö ä ß -- in the pagenote}}
    
    A pagenote with an URL (href command) including german Umlaute ä ö ü ß :\pagenote{\href{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles#Fr%C3%BChe_Jahre_(1956%E2%80%931960)}{A href link including german Umlaute ä ö ü ß -- in the pagenote}}

    A pagenote with an URL (url command) including german Umlaute ä ö ü ß :\pagenote{\url{https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles#Fr%C3%BChe_Jahre_(1956%E2%80%931960)} A url ink including german Umlaute ä ü ö ß -- in the pagenote}

\printnotes

\end{document}
```

Currently this MWE results in displaying only the first pagenote with the correcsponding link. The second and third pagenote-links are ignored with the above error message and will not be displayed in the pagenotes.

Comment: you can not use % and # directly if you put the url in the argument of another command, hyperref then can not do its magic to change the catcode.  You must escape all percents with `\%` and the hash with `\#`.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike Fischer, that was simple. And worked. And obviously there is no automatic use of it when putting it in the `\href{}` and use the hyperref package in addition the the `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` to get it automatic? This is what I had expected.

Comment: you get the runaway argument error before \href was even seen, so hyperref can not prevent it. But you can store urls in commands, see \urldef in the url package (loaded by hyperref).

Comment: Ok, thank you Ulrike Fischer. I will see. It is fine for me with these `\%` and `\#` neccesities. Would you like to do the `answer` for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments Ulrike Fischer gave the answer:

Use `\#` and `\%` within the url address instead of leaving the `#` and `%` alone.

Second I found that tex4ebook has problems with this solution, it needs a "plain" url address. So I used the `\urldef{\myurl}\url{Some-complete-and-plain-url-address}`, which is described in the `url package` and used by the `hyperref package`. Which solved the problem only partly.

It turned out that a problem then arises with the `ebgaramond font package` while running tex4ebook. Which forced me to use another font package, that I integrated to my `preamble` as follows:

```
...
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage{Somefontpackage}% which is loaded when tex4ebook is running
\else
\usepackage{Someotherfontpackage}% which is loaded when pdflatex is running
\fi
...
```